# How to enable menu click when hiding div for responsive layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a navigation that hides the sub-navigation menu `.nav-sub-wrapper` when resizing to tablet/mobile. The issue is that with this specific jQuery used to hide the menu on resize, it is disabling the menu from showing on mobile/tablet devices when clicking the menu (`.hamburger`) icon.

How can I enable the `.hamburger` menu to trigger the `.nav-sub-wrapper` class to display on click?

```
if($(window).width() <= '768'){
$(".nav-sub-wrapper, .desktop-search-box").hide();
$(".hamburger").on('click', function(){
  if($(".logo-link").css("display") == 'none'){
    $(".hamburger").addClass("hamburger-active");
  }
  $('.list-header').trigger('click');
  $(".nav-sub-wrapper").toggle();
  $(".search").show();
});
}

//used to hide nav on resize//
function navHidden() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    $(".nav-sub-wrapper").hide();
    $(".hamburger").on('click', function() {
      $(".nav-sub-wrapper").toggle();
    });
    } else {
      $(".nav-sub-wrapper").show();
    }
  }

  $(window).resize(function() {
    navHidden();
  });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    navHidden();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to make sure you are unbinding the earlier hamburger "on" click event. When the page first loads at full screen, the click function is bound to the ".hamburger" element due to your first line of code.

```
if($(window).width() <= 768) {
   // Any event bindings you create here will still exist
   // even if you create a new binding somewhere else.
}
```

It doesn't matter if you resize to Desktop mode and this initial conditional (screen width <= 768) is no longer met, the click function defined here is still bound to the ".hamburger" element.

That means when you resize and click ".hamburger" in mobile mode, you are running both the mobile function and the earlier bound functions simultaneously. So you are toggling the nav twice, once on, once off. That is why you are having an issue.

Try this:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
    //Remove anything still bound from earlier that could be causing a double-fire.
    $(".hamburger").off('click');
    $(".hamburger").on('click', function() {
        $(".nav-sub-wrapper").toggle();
    });
}
```

Hope this helps,

Sean

P.S.:

Might want to refactor to something like this in the long run, which I think is a bit cleaner:

```
function isViewportMobile() {
 if($(window).width() <= 768) {
   return true;
  }
}

$(window).on("resize", function(){
   if (!isViewportMobile()) {
     useDesktopRules();
   } else {
     useMobileRules();
   }
});
```

Where useDesktopRules and useMobileRules would contain the jQuery/dom-manipulation code you provided earlier for each viewport.

[Consider using a "throttling / debouncing" function as well](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function), to prevent millions of function calls when the resize happens.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To clarify what you're saying though, do you mean I should remove the first event handler binding to `.hamburger` on lines 3-10, and move the hide function to the if statement you provided?

Comment: You don't have to necessarily remove the first event handler binding from the code, you just need to make sure you use "off" right before declaring "on". If click function bound to .hamburger was already set somewhere else, it will clear the binding, if it wasn't, it won't do anything and your code will act as it already does. Using the code you gave, without any refactoring considerations, I would likely call .off before BOTH .on bindings you make in their respective conditionals.

Comment: I'm finding that the resize function is actually disabling some features from showing up on tablet when clicking the `.hamburger` icon. The `.search` icon does not show on tablet, but does on mobile. Also, I have to refresh the page when resizing to correctly use the navigation. 

When expanding the window to desktop, I can't access the menu through the `.search` icon anymore without having to refresh the page.

I've included a fiddle of all of the JS to hopefully make this clearer. There is a lot of JS, but I've commented on the important sections. https://jsfiddle.net/707e8cnv/